# Xquery. Trying to make a table from 2 xml files. Getting "$y is not set" error

Tags: html, xpath, html-table, xquery, exist-db

Here is my code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>tabla comentarios</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table border='1'>              
        {                               
        for $x in doc("/db/books/books.xml")/bookstore/book/title, $y in doc("/db/books/comentarios.xml")/entradas_comentario/entrada/titulo
        where $x = $y/titulo
        return
        <tr>                                    
            <td> {data($x)}</td>
            <td> {data($y/comentarios)}</td>                                    
        </tr>   
        }
    </table>                
</body>
```

I used the exact same code in school and it worked there (literally copy pasted from my pc there) but at home I keep getting this error:

```
err:XPDY0002 variable '$y' is not set. [at line 9, column 37, source: <html> <head> <title>tabla comentarios</title> </head> <body> <table border='1'>  {   for $x in doc("/db/books/books.xml")/bookstore/book/title, $y in doc("/db/books/comentarios.xml")/entradas_comentario/entrada/titulo where $x = $y/titulo return <tr> <td> {data($x)}</td> <td> {data($y/comentarios)}</td> </tr> } </table>    </body> </html>]
```

Talked with some classmates and they have the exact came problem.
I'm using eXistDB.

Comment: It looks like a bug. If you are using eXistDB on both sides, it could be that one version contains a fix. Maybe using two explicit `for` clauses rather than one single compound clause could circumvent the issue for the other.

Comment: provided that the paths are correct it should just work. Two separate `for` clauses  is a good idea, you might also try to add two `//` like this `doc('some/thing.xml')//root/...` .

Comment: Which version of eXist is running at school vs. at home?